# find where with same attribute and more than 2 values in yii2 mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I can count it with one ObjectId as shown below.

```
public function count_typesA() {
    $list = Shops::findAll(['typeid'=>new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("57eb8395b5ea6a14c00075d2")]);
    return count($list);
}
```

I have to count all the typeid with  `57ea5880b5ea6a0650002785` and `57eb8395b5ea6a14c00075d2`.
 (Same attribute `typeid` with different values)
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could help:

```
public function count_typesA() {
    $list = Shops::findAll(['typeid'=> [
        new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("57eb8395b5ea6a14c00075d2"),
        new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("57ea5880b5ea6a0650002785")
      ]
    ]);
    return count($list);
}
```

Comment: saved my time!  :)

Comment: Glad it help you out! You can upvote the answer as well. :)